# Change NSTextField border and BG color while editing

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a `NSTextField` that uses no border and window background color while it is displayed but I want it to change to have the default border and white BG color when being edited. I know I can change these properties with:

```
nameTextField.bezeled = true
nameTextField.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor()
```

What I don't know is how to be notified when the textfield is started to be edited and when it's ended. There seem to be no actions for this. Is there any other way how could this behaviour be achieved?

EDIT:
Actually, edit end can be detected via the textfield's change action when setting Action to "Send on End Editing" so that's solved but still how do I detect start editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `delegate` of `NSTextField`:

```
nameTextField.delegate = self
```

then you can set a different state:

```
func control(control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    nameTextField.bezeled = true
    nameTextField.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor()

    return true
}
func control(control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    nameTextField.bezeled = false
    nameTextField.backgroundColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor()

    return true
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think you can subclass `NSTextField` and override the `becomeFirstResponder` and the `resignFirstResponder`, then you know the `NSTextField` has the focus or not.

Comment: Ok thanks but the problem with those  is that they are only invoked if the text actually changed.

Comment: You can also to see if the `window`'s `firstResponder` is the `NSTextField`

Comment: Overriding the firstReponder methods makes it work, thanks for the help! What I noticed though is that `nameTextField.bezeled = true/false` actually doesn't work when used in the overriden methods (and neither in the delegate methods). It wont change to have the border and just stays without the border, as I set it in IB.

Comment: This post maybe useful to you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568054/change-border-color-of-nstextfield

Comment: Thanks for the link! Still, quite a bit overkill to have to redraw the whole border with a bezier for this simple purpose.

Comment: Did you try to call `nameTextField.setNeedsDisplay()` after setting `bezeled` to true/false?