# Change NSTextField text color when in edit mode

Tags: appkit, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell, nsviewrepresentable

Using NSTextField I'd like to change the text color from black to white when going into edit mode.

Right now, it:

1. Defaults to black when not selected (**GOOD**)

[image]

2. Defaults to white when selected (**GOOD**)

[image]

3. Changes color to black when editing starts (**NOT GOOD**), **would like for it to be white.**

[image]

I know I could set the textColor property to .white but that would also set the color to white when the row is not selected (see point 1.), which I don't want. Huge thanks in advance!

Code I'm using now for reference, note is part of a NSViewRepresentable struct.

```
func makeNSView(context:Context) -> NSTextField{
    let osTextView = NSTextField(string: inputText)
    osTextView.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
    osTextView.isBordered = false
    osTextView.delegate = context.coordinator
    osTextView.drawsBackground = true
    osTextView.backgroundColor = .none
    //osTextView.textColor = .white
    
    return osTextView
}
```

I've tried adding the following and it almost gets the job done, however it only triggers when edit begins as opposed to when NSTextField becomes editable.

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
        fieldEditor.textColor = .white
        return true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "I'd like to change the text color from white to black" and "would like for it to be white", do you want black or white text? What does selected white text look like?

Comment: I’d like when the cell is selected and changes into edit mode (see #3 above) to use white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change NSTextField border and BG color while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859814/change-nstextfield-border-and-bg-color-while-editing)

Comment: I wish, unfortunately this only changes the color once you start typing, but not when you have clicked on it - making the text editable -. Uploading a GIF now to help illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I managed to solve it is by subclassing NSTextField and overriding becomeFirstResponder. As that only triggers when the field goes into edit mode I can set there the color to white.

```
import AppKit

final class NSTextFieldFirstResponderAware: NSTextField{

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    self.textColor = .white
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
}

}
```

Once the user finishes I reset the color at

```
func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        guard let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField else {
            return
        }
        
        textField.textColor = nil
}
```

You may wonder why I don't reset it at resignsFirstResponder, the reason is [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109158) (TLDR -> would not work).

And here is the end result:

[image: rows changing colors as intended]