# Cant change border color in Cocoa Swift Mac OS

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am new to Cocoa with Swift and made a textfield programmatically like this:

```
let usernameTextField: NSTextField = {
        let textField = NSTextField()
        textField.isBezeled = false
        textField.drawsBackground = false
        textField.focusRingType = .none
        textField.placeholderString = "Username"
        textField.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }()
```

Later, in `viewDidLoad`, I do this:

```
usernameTextField.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.systemRed.cgColor
```

But the color doesn't change to red. Why is this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change border color of NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568054/change-border-color-of-nstextfield)

Comment: @Willeke No, this is in Obj c and I am referring specifically to changing it after it has been set. Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762691/4244136, replace `self` by `usernameTextField`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding border width:

```
usernameTextField.layer?.borderWidth = 2
```

or don't add it in viewDidLoad() try adding it in viewWillLayoutSubviews()

Comment: The border shows up as the original color set in the closure, however, I want to change it to red. This is what doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Have no idea if this is helpful or not, but it will change a subclassed NSTextField's border color:

```
import Cocoa

var borderColor = NSColor()

class TextField: NSTextField {
override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
  super.draw(rect)
  let border = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
  borderColor.set()
  border.lineWidth = 2.0
  border.stroke()
}

@objc func changeBorderColor(_ sender: AnyObject ) {
 borderColor = .red
 self.needsDisplay = true
}

}
let txtFld = TextField()

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
 var window: NSWindow!

func buildMenu() {
 let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}
    
func buildWnd() {
let _wndW:CGFloat = 400
let _wndH:CGFloat = 200

 window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

// === Text Field === //
let txtFld = TextField (frame:NSMakeRect( 60, 60, 180, 24 ))
window.contentView!.addSubview(txtFld)
txtFld.stringValue = "Text"
borderColor = .green

// === Button === //
 let myBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( 150, 100, 135, 30 ))
 myBtn.bezelStyle = .rounded
 myBtn.title = "Change Border"
 myBtn.target = txtFld
 myBtn.action = #selector(txtFld.changeBorderColor(_:))
 window.contentView!.addSubview (myBtn)

// === Quit btn === //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}

let appDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
application.delegate = appDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```